# Menu in Toolbar - Ext-JS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

When I press button, I want a menu but it's not working and when I press the button, nothing happens. Here is the code:

```
{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'menu',
                    menu: Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
                            width: 100,
                            plain: true,
                            floating: false,  // usually you want this set to True (default)
                            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                            items: [{
                                    text: 'plain item 1'
                                },{
                                    text: 'plain item 2'
                                },{
                                    text: 'plain item 3'
                            }]
                        })
                },
```

Where is the problem?

SOLVED:

**Just deleted floating: false. :)**

Comment: Answer your own question if you solved it :)

Comment: And don't use `renderTo:` when the menu is contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

Just deleted floating: false. :)